# Converting existing webapplication to native android app

Tags: php, android, angularjs, spring-mvc

Let us say I have 3 dynamic website for example built using

I- Spring MVC 
II- PHP
III-Angular JS

I am an Android developer who likes to built native customized android apps (without WebView).

1. Do I need knowledge of any of I, II or III frameworks to create my android app or can I just do it completely independent?
2. If I need knowledge of I, II or III frameworks, how much would I need?
3. Do I use Android's AsyncTask or Volley API's to accomplish this task? I am asking this because I am new to Android.

Thank you for your help in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Android developer in this case you don't need knowledge of any of these PHP and JS frameworks. You only need to access the "data" of these websites through any kind of Web API. Normally such APIs use JSON or XML data to communicate.
In Android i think Volley is a good library to access remote data like JSON but you can use any other library which can handle XML or JSON data.